# Is there an established concept slightly weaker than torsion, as defined like this?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology, torsion-groups

Let $\sim$ be an equivalence relation over an algebraic object $X$ whereby there is a modular algebra $X/{\sim},\star$.

> Does there already exist a concept ever so slightly weaker than torsion, whereby if $[x]$ is a representative of some element of $X/{\sim}$ then $\lvert [x]\star [x]\rvert=\lvert [x]\rvert$, but for all distinct $[x_1],[x_2]\in X :\lvert[x_1]\star[x_2]\rvert<\max\{\lvert[x_1]\rvert,\lvert[x_2]\rvert\}$

I've not defined $\lvert\cdot\rvert$ which would take a little work but this measures something analogous to the order in a group.

An example of this property applies to the multiplicative monoid of odd, positive numbers (with each odd number $[x]$ a representative of $\langle2\rangle[x]$).  In this case (nonassociative) addition of the representatives is the modular operation with the required property.  In this example we have e.g. $26\star 44=[13+11]=3$

Comment: Did you miss that there is a $|.|$ in your inequality ?

Comment: @reuns I have just checked carefully and I think they are all in order

Comment: @reuns I should perhaps clarify my answer to your comment.  I wasn't clear whether you were pointing out a perceived syntactic error, or hinting in a roundabout way that I've used $\lvert\cdot\rvert$ within the question without defining it precisely.  I elected for the first interpretation but if you meant the latter, I can add a more precise definition if it's needed to clarify the question.